# Extending fluent nhibernate mappings in another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate with my ASP.Net MVC application.
I'm writing some extensions (plugins) for my application. And I'm loading those plugin dynamically (from different assemblies). 
In my base application I have many entities and mappings defined (User, Group, etc...)

I need to create new entities in my extensions, so i.e. I'm creating News module, so I need to create News mapping.
In database News table has a foreign key to User table.
Is there any way I can modify my User mapping, so it will have:

```
HasMany(x => x.News)
  .KeyColumn("UserId")
  .Inverse();
```

Or the only way to do it is to change code in my User class and recompile project ?

I'm not NHibernate advanced user, so any help will be appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: errr, you want to dynamically add a property to User?

Comment: yes, something like that I think ;) Maby there is totally different way to achieve that.

Comment: Mappings are created once, on application startup, do you know the structure of your entity by that point?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I understand your question correctly :)
I'm creating all mappings in Application_Start method (global asax).
All my extensions/plugins are loaded on application startup.

Comment: Im also looking for an answear to this one. Is there any possibility with nhibernate to extend an entity from within another map without touching the "main"-map ?

Answer (score 1):

Fluent NHibernate might help

Check the sections on [Fluent Mapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping) or, even better, [Auto Mapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping)

The Auto Mapping can be overridden for individual properties if you can't use the default.  Also, with fluent NHibernate, you can specify your own defaults for primary keys, foreign keys and the like.

Comment: +1. I know automapping, but how can I add News property to User class ?

Answer (score 1):

You can automap multiple assemblies, e.g.

```
AutoMap.Assemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), 
                   typeof(MyType).Assembly)
```

will map the executing assembly, and the assembly that contains "MyType".

Note that this is a relatively new feature (Feb 19, 2010) in FNH, so make sure you have a recent build.

Not sure how this would work in a dynamic loading situation, but I think that's more of an issue with how you would get the list of assemblies (via reflection, probably) than NHibernate per se.